# How to get all tweets of user in asp.net using Twitterizer

Tags: asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have twitter access token,customer key,and corresponding secret key.

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
        tokens.AccessToken = "XXXXXXXX";
        tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "XXXXxxx";
        tokens.ConsumerKey = "XXXXXXXXXX";
        tokens.ConsumerSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXX";


  TwitterResponse<TwitterUser> showUserResponse = TwitterUser.Show(tokens,"<USERID>");
```

But i have included all dll given  `Twitterizer`.

How to get all tweets from my twitter account and also tweet from asp.net applicatio as well.

how to solve it?

Any other way to access all tweets using `Twitterizer`

Comment: Please expand your question to include the relavent code. That should help us to help you.